# Hosting node application on separate computer than Apache web server

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, node.js, mod-alias

I am attempting to create a virtual host to connect a computer running a node application (Computer B 12.34.56.78) to a computer running my Apache web server (Computer A 12.34.56.77). Everything I have seen so far just deals with serving a node application running on the same computer that is running the Apache instance.

In the end I would like to be able to access the Node application using a URL such as defaultwebsite.com/nodeapp.

Has anybody had experience doing this? I am still relatively new to working with Apache and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for Reverse Proxy. It's quite simple, configure your Apache server that serves the `defaultwebsite.com` (Computer A, 12.34.56.77) a Reverse Proxy like this:

```
<Location /nodeapp>
    ProxyPass http://12.34.56.78/
    ProxyPassReverse http://12.34.56.78/
</Location>
```

For more, take a look at the [Reverse Proxy Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) and [mod_proxy configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: Would this be something that would be included in the main .conf file such as default-ssl.conf/000-default.conf? Or, could I create another .conf file called nodeApp.conf and just add those lines to it?

Comment: I guess your default-ssl.conf/000-default.conf contains a VirtualHost. If so, put it inside the VirtualHost.